# Solving differential equations in a loop with different parameters each time R

Tags: r, dsolve

I think, this should be simple.
I'm solving numerically a set of differential equations in R. When I do it one it is fine. However I need to test the set of differential equations for several groups of parameters, thus I am using a loop. The problem is that for all the set of parameters it shows the same values, which is not right.

```
contrand<-sample(paste0("p",1:18), 
                 size=nb, replace=TRUE, 
                 prob=c(0, 0, 0.052, 0.013, 0.033,  0.017, 0.002,0.026, 0.005, 0.093, 
                        0.186, 0.006, 0.001, 0.004, 0.0044, 0.4395, 0.005, 0.113))

z.cont <- data.frame(matrix(rep(NA,1*nb),nrow=nb,ncol=1))
for (i in 1:nb){
    params <- get(contrand[i])
    model<-function(t,x,params){
      S<-x[1]
      I<-x[2]
      R<-x[3]
      with(as.list(params),{
        N<- S+I+R
        dS <- birth*N - beta*S*I- death*S
        dI <- beta*S*I - gamma*I - death*I
        dR <- gamma*I - death*R

        dx <- c(dS,dI,dR)
        list(dx)
      })
    }
    out<-as.data.frame(lsoda(xstart,times,model,params))
    I<-as.data.frame(out$I)
    z.cont[i,1] <- Iv[157,]
}
```

Comment: What is `contrand`? Whatever it is, I don't think you need `get`.

Comment: It is the set of parameters defined in each p `contrand<-sample(c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p5","p6","p7","p8","p9","p10","p11","p12","p13","p14","p15","p16","p17","p18"),
                 size=nb, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0,0,0.052,0.013,0.033,0.017,0.002,0.026,0.005,0.093,0.186,0.006,0.001,0.004,0.0044,0.4395,0.005,0.113))`

Comment: What is your output? Obejcts out and I are rewritten in every loop. Though this won't make a It looks like you can pull your model function out of the loop. In addition, I don't see where object Iv is defined. I don't see it relying on the iterated variable i. There should be no need to rebuild the function every iteration.

Comment: You're sampling p1 and p2 with probability 0? but yeah, try removing the `get`, and if you need more help, add a minimal dataset that reproduces the error (To the question), currently this is not reproducible, which makes anything other than a quick eyeball impossible.

Comment: Can you clarify which package you are using? Is this deSolve or odesolve. If it's deSolve? i think your tag has a typo...it says dsolve.

Comment: The copy-pasted version of this had a non-printing character in the number `0.004` that caused an error.  The `nb` variable is undefined and its purpose unclear to me. If there are supposed to be objects in the workspace named "p1"-"p18" then the `get` might make sense .... otherwise its purpose is also unclear. Don't make up new tags unless you document them.